# Disabling all rubber in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, lengths

Situations like the following cause wiggling text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{itemize}
            \itemsep=2.5pt
            \item<1-> Many
            \item<1-> Bullet
            \item<1-> Points \only<-1>{\[\rule{6em}{8em}\]}
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

because the rubber in the itemization gets condensed when the black rectangle is contained in the slide. Can I mitigate this somehow? For example, I can set `\itemsep=2pt` at the beginning of the list. But there are also other rubber lengths contributing to the wiggling (I don't know which). Is there an easy switch to make all relevant lengths fixed for a single slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `\@listi` and remove the stretch from all the lengths:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \topsep 3\p@
            \parsep 0\p@
            \itemsep3\p@}
\let\@listI\@listi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Many
            \item<1-> Bullet
            \item<1-> Points \only<-1>{\[\rule{6em}{8em}\]}
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
            \item<2-> Some
            \item<2-> More
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]